# MySQL resource's fetched row count

Tags: php, mysql

Looked all over and couldn't find a way to do this.

I want to count the amount of results from a query that's being looped.

for example...

If I have 5 pokemon, and 2 of them are Pikachus, it will display 4 pokemon but with a 2 next to the pikachu, I want to count the number of different pokemon you own not including the secound Pikachu.

this is what I have so far.

```
<div class="reg-box3" style="width:100%; margin:5px;">
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, COUNT(*) number FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION{'username'}."'AND (slot='0') GROUP BY pokemon ORDER BY pokemon");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE name='".$row['pokemon']."'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
$battle_get2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

?>
<div style="width: 24.5%; float: left;padding:.1%; ">
<?php

$idd= mysql_real_escape_string($row['id']);
$iddd = strip_tags($idd);

?>
```

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` is used to escape user data in SQL query, not output of the query. Instead of querying pokemon by name for each row, what about `JOIN`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use a JOIN, I'm quite new to coding.

Comment: Try this `SELECT *, COUNT(*) number FROM user_pokemon INNER JOIN pokemon ON(pokemon.name = user_pokemon.pokemon) WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION{'username'}."'AND (slot='0') GROUP BY pokemon ORDER BY pokemon` and examinate `$row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `AS` from your query before `number`. If you add it, the desired count will be stored in the `$result['number']` variable.

By the way you might find `mysql_num_rows()` easier in this case. Just call it on your MySQL resource, and it returns the number of rows fetched.

Edit: using `mysql_num_rows` is this simple: `$count = mysql_num_rows($result);`

Comment: `AS` is optional in SQL. :(

Comment: Nope, doesn't work it still just gives me the amount of individual pokemon, I want the entire amount through the loop.

Comment: Then remove the GROUP BY.

Comment: I use the GROUP BY to group common pokemon.

Comment: I have not, I've never used it before so idk how to tbh.

Comment: I've added how you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query(
<<<SQL
    SELECT
        `t2`.`name` AS `name`,
        COUNT(*) AS `count`
    FROM `user_pokemon` AS `t1`
        JOIN `pokemon` AS `t2` ON (`t1`.`pokemon` = `t2`.`name`)
    WHERE
        `t1`.`belongsto` = '{$_SESSION{'username'}}'
        AND `t1`.`slot` = 0
    GROUP BY `name`
    ORDER BY `name`
SQL
);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    var_dump($row);
}
?>
```

No guarantees it works as I don't know your table structure and not sure if I got it right from your queries.

**PS**: *Don't count records with `mysql_num_rows()`. It requires transferring data from the server while, if you do it directly in MySQL, you get the maximum of performance with the most ease of use.*